# ckeditor widget firefox bug

Tags: firefox, widget, ckeditor

I think there's a bug on widget on firefox (version 39 on both OSX and Windows).  http://ckeditor.com/demo#widgets
When clicking on part of the widget to edit, the cursor is always at the beginning instead of where you click.  Cannot move left and right at all. Cursor up would go to the beginning and down would to to the end of the line

Any CKEditor developers can shed any light on this?

Comment: I got the same behaviour, and even more. It clearly happens only with Firefox. You can look at [the issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1187475) I reported.

Comment: Bug [confirmed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1181130) by Mozilla, should be fixed soon (Firefox 40).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. This issue is caused by a contenteditable bug in Firefox 39. Update your Firefox to 40+ in order to resolve the issue. This is not an issue specific to CKEditor.